# Springs new RestClient appears to retry but only on status 429

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

```
        val restClient = RestClient.builder()
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
            .baseUrl(simproWebhookContext.inboundWebhookUrl!!)
            .build()

        restClient.post()
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(deriveSimproContactJsonBody(custContact, siteContact, simproWebhookContext))
            .retrieve()
            .toBodilessEntity()
```

in my unit tests, this works exactly as expected except when I set the mock status to 429

```
    wm1.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/test-inboundWebhookUrl"))
        .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(400)))
```

val requests = findAll(postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/test-inboundWebhookUrl")))
assertEquals(requests.size, 1)

but if I set it to 429

wm1.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/test-inboundWebhookUrl"))
.willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(429)))

the requests.size is always 2

There is no logic in my code that traps in any way for 429, so I'm assuming this is a feature in the RestClient code.

Where / how can I configure the retry logic?

Here's my spring boot version: id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may depend on http client used underneath RestClient. If you're using Apache http client 5 then disabling automatic retries might do the trick.

```
    var client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .disableAutomaticRetries()
            .build();

    return RestClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .requestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client)))
            .build();
```

https://www.baeldung.com/java-retrying-requests-using-apache-httpclient